# How to add spinner in Slider menu in android

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I have one slider menu in that I need to add the spinner so that it should add the dropdown list but its not working please anyone suggest the solution
I have created one method in that method I have wrote the spinner code

```
    package com.dfhrms;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.StyleableRes;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import info.androidhive.slidingmenu.adapter.NavDrawerListAdapter;
import info.androidhive.slidingmenu.model.NavDrawerItem;

import static com.dfhrms.CommonUtilities.EXTRA_MESSAGE;

    public class Slide_MainActivity extends Activity {
        private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
        private ListView mDrawerList;
    Spinner spinner;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    @StyleableRes
    int index = 1;
    String[] country = { "India", "USA", "China", "Japan", "Other",  };
    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;
    String username,pwd,manual;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.slide_activity_main);
        SharedPreferences myprefs= getSharedPreferences("user",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        //Toast.makeText(Instant.this,myprefs.getAll().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        username = myprefs.getString("user1", "nothing");
        manual = myprefs.getString("manual", "nothing");
        pwd = myprefs.getString("pwd", "nothing");
        spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);
        //navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(index, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        //  navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1), true, "22"));
        // Pages
        //  navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
        //  navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1), true, "50+"));


        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        //  getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility



                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            //displayView(position);
            String country = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
    public void   logOut()
    {
        // Toast.makeText(Home.this,"Hi",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if(manual.equals("yes")) {
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(username, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.remove("logged");
            editor.commit();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,
                    login.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);

            finish();
        }
        else
        {
            if(manual.equals("no")) {
                signOut();

            }
        }

    }

    public void Hiring(){


        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                       int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                displayView(2);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, country);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


    }


    /* *
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */



    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                //  fragment = new PhotosFragment();

                logOut();
                break;
            case 2:
                setContentView(R.layout.fragment_photos);
                //fragment = new PhotosFragment();
                Hiring();
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new CommunityFragment();
                break;
            case 4:
                fragment = new PagesFragment();
                break;
            case 5:
                fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
            // Waking up mobile if it is sleeping

            /**
             * Take appropriate action on this message
             * depending upon your app requirement
             * For now i am just displaying it on the screen
             * */

            // Showing received message
            //  lblMessage.append(newMessage + "\n");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New Message: " + newMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    };
    private void signOut() {
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),login.class);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        super.onStart();
    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        return (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK ? true : super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event));
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {


        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

Comment: What is not working ? Clarify it.

Comment: When I click on dropdown button Unfortunately stopped error im getting

Comment: So there is some error log. Post it.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(android.widget.AdapterView$OnItemSelectedListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                at com.dfhrms.Slide_MainActivity.Hiring(Slide_MainActivity.java:207)
                                                                at com.dfhrms.Slide_MainActivity.displayView(Slide_MainActivity.java:256)
                                                                at com.dfhrms.Slide_MainActivity.access$300

Comment: Its a null pointer exception means one of your object is null. For eg , spinner or any other object which could not be initialized.

Comment: @ParimalaDesai can u post full code

Comment: I have posted full code

Answer (score 0):

use this for making a spinner

```
   class AndroidSpinnerExampleActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

  // Spinner element
  Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

  // Spinner click listener
  spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

  // Spinner Drop down elements
  List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
  categories.add("Automobile");
  categories.add("Business Services");
  categories.add("Computers");
  categories.add("Education");
  categories.add("Personal");
  categories.add("Travel");

  // Creating adapter for spinner
  ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);

  // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
  dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

  // attaching data adapter to spinner
  spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}

 @Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
  // On selecting a spinner item
  String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

  // Showing selected spinner item
  Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 }
 }
```

for more refer  [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_spinner_control.htm)